# Is there any better way of defining if() condition using PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there any better way of redefining this `if()`, what i dislike about this statement is `$prefix` is repeated again and again and it looks ugly to me.

```
if($prefix == 'RSVH' || 
   $prefix == 'RSAP' || 
   $prefix == 'CMOS' || 
   $prefix == 'CMSR' || 
   $prefix == 'CMKS' || 
   $prefix == 'CMWH' || 
   $prefix == 'CMBL' || 
   $prefix == 'LNRS' || 
   $prefix == 'LNCM' || 
   $prefix == 'LNMX' || 
   $prefix == 'PMNG');
```

thank you..

Comment: you could also use switch/case but the suggestions below are better assuming you an put the prefixes in an array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an array and the function [in_array()](http://www.php.net/in-array):

```
$values = array('RSVH', 'RSAP', 'CMOS' /*, ... */);

if ( in_array($prefix, $values) )
{
  /* do something */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Probably I would use [`in_array()`](http://us.php.net/manual/function.in-array.php)

```
if (in_array($prefix, array('RSVH','RSAP','CMOS'.....))
{
   // It's in there...
}
```

Comment: yeah, this looks better, hold it in an array and check if it exist in an array :)